# How to update primefaces DataTable inside tabView and layoutUnit?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have next code:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" size="50%" styleClass="nestedUnit">

            <p:tabView id="tableTabView>

                <p:tab title="Inbox">

                    <h:form id="tableForm">

                        <p:dataTable id="tableMsg">

                            //data

                        </p:dataTable>

                    </h:form>

                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>

        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>
```

Also I have some button, which removing element from table and update It. But how I can update this table? Which arguments should be in update? I'm tried `update=":tableForm"` and `update=":tableTabView:tableForm"` and `update=":tableTabView"` but not results. Where I was wrong?

Comment: `update="@form"` for the whole form or `update=":tableForm:tableMsg"` for the table only should work.

Comment: @XtremeBiker It's not working, because 'javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":tableForm:tableMsg"'
My button is not inside current layoutUnit.

Comment: Open firebug or developer tools in your web browser. See what value is the component aquiring at client side and put that id in your `update` attribute.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thank you very much. Answer to topic and I will accept him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open firebug or developer tools in your web browser. See what value is the component aquiring at client side and put that id in your `update` attribute.